# How can I animate a div element in an ellipse shape along a specified SVG path using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to animate a div element in the shape of an ellipse, following a specified SVG path. I have the SVG path defined, and I want to smoothly move the div element along that path. What is the best approach to achieve this effect using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript?

```html
<section class="mission-statement">
  <svg class="vector" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1650" height="721" viewBox=" 0 0 1650 821"><g clip-path="url(#a)"><path id="motionPath" stroke="#fff" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-opacity=".6" stroke-width="1.5" d="M1728 410.5c-264.11 443.383-336.42 443.383-125.14 0 164.7-247.83 138.29-247.83-79.23 0-264.11 247.83-290.52 247.83-79.23 0 202.21-226.532 175.8-226.532-79.23 0-264.11 226.532-290.52 226.532-79.24 0 330.48-482.106 304.07-482.106-79.23 0-264.108 482.106-290.519 482.106-79.23 0 222.74-534.383 196.33-534.383-79.23 0-264.113 534.383-290.524 534.383-79.237 0 167.267-311.723 140.857-311.723-79.232 0-264.109 311.723-290.52 311.723-79.233 0 223.752-348.51 197.342-348.51-79.233 0-264.108 348.511-290.519 348.511-79.232 0C897.4-50.309 870.99-50.309 572.84 410.5c-264.108 460.809-290.519 460.809-79.232 0 213.506-470.49 187.095-470.49-79.233 0-264.108 470.489-290.519 470.489-79.232 0 228.242-546 201.831-546-79.233 0-264.108 546-290.52 546-79.233 0C365.112-17.394 241.257-17.394 0 410.5"/></g><defs><clipPath id="a"><path fill="#fff" d="M0 0h1728v821H0z"/></clipPath></defs></svg>
  <div class="ellipse"></div>
</section>
```

I want the div with the id "ellipse" to move along the path automatically back and forth continously defined by the SVG path element with the id "motionPath". How can I accomplish this animation? Are there any JavaScript libraries or techniques that could help me achieve this effect?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

One way to accomplish this is with SMIL and `<animateMotion>`.  In this example, I cleaned up your SVG a bit and used just the path portion for the motion path.  Then I applied it to a `<circle>` element that has a radius of 25 and a fill color of blue.  The `dur` property sets the animation duration and the `fill` property when set to `freeze` causes the circle to "freeze" on the last frame of the animation, rather than return to the start.

```css
svg {
  height: 90vh;
}
```

```html
<section class="mission-statement">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 1100 690" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="100%" width="100%">
    <circle r="25" fill="blue">
      <animateMotion
        dur="20s"
        fill="freeze"
        path="M124.36,344.22c-185.55,458.08-162.36,458.08,69.58,0,246.83-458.08,270.02-458.08,69.58,0-185.55,394.73-162.36,394.73,69.58,0,233.89-394.73,257.08-394.73,69.58,0-185.55,386.61-162.36,386.61,69.58,0,261.83-386.61,285.03-386.61,69.58,0-185.55,292.39-162.36,292.39,69.58,0,242.89-292.39,266.08-292.39,69.58,0-185.55,261.53-131.3,280.39,69.58,0,193.28-261.53,216.47-261.53,69.58,0-185.98,318.28-162.49,409.19,69.59,0,242-448.33,265.19-448.33,69.58" />
    </circle>
  </svg>
</section>
```

SMIL actually has good browser support (despite Chrome deprecating and then later un-deprecating it). It even works with the `<img>` tag and as a background-image in CSS in many browsers.

Learn more [here](https://css-tricks.com/guide-svg-animations-smil/) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/SVG_animation_with_SMIL).